# How to clone a Vector

Tags: scala

I have the following method, where `cards` is of type `Vector[Card]`.
As `cards` is a field, I want to return a clone of it.

I tried this:

```
class Deck(cards: Vector[Card] = Vector.empty[Card]) {

    //other methods

    def getCards(): Vector[Card] = {
        return cards.clone()
      }
}
```

However, I am getting:

```
Error:(31, 18) method clone in class Object cannot be accessed in Vector[<error>]
 Access to protected method clone not permitted because
 prefix type Vector[<error>] does not conform to
 class Deck in package genericGame where the access take place
    return cards.clone()
                 ^
```

So how can I clone the field?

Comment: Vectors are immutable. Just return `cards`, nothing can modify it (if you look at the Cloneable trait, you'll see it's only used for mutable collections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to, just return `cards`, cloning is usually needed for mutable objects where you need to take a copy of the object and work on them independently from source because the source can change later.

It is not the case for `Vector` since it is immutable, you can safely hold a reference to it and it will always hold the same value/s of `Card` unless Card itself is mutable, then you can add a method to copy a Card and do a `map`.

```
class Card(var name:String){
  def copy() = new Card(this.name)
}
val copy: Vector[Card] = vector.map(_.copy())
```

But as I said, all this wouldn't be needed if `Card` is immutable (`case` classes for instance) then you can safley use your `Vector` without any copies.